# Bash: can't delete first 3 elements from array

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have an array, which I got from the file. This array contains empty elements and I don't need to use first 3 elements from array. All of it I need to delete.

```
 FILE="$1"

 index=0
 while read name; do
    get_group_names_from_file[$index]="$name"
    index=$(($index+1))
 done < "${FILE}"

 for i in 2; do
   unset get_group_names_from_file[$i]
 done

 for ((a=0; a < ${#get_group_names_from_file[*]}; a++))
 do
   echo "${get_group_names_from_file[$a]}"
 done
```

unset just replace my first 2 elements by empty elements. How can I delete empty elements from get_group_names_from_file?

## Update:

I deleted first 2 elements from array, the last problem is to delete empty elements from array; How can I do this?

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Don't pile on new questions. Instead, accept the answer you got (or post one of your own and accept that if you like) and ask a new question. Of course, check for duplicates before asking things which have already been answered before. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(abc def 'ghi jkl' mno)
arr=("${arr[@]:2}")
printf '<%s>\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

You can also use `shift`. It only operates on the positinal parameters, though, so you need to use `set` and then assign the result back:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(abc def 'ghi jkl' mno)
set -- "${arr[@]}"
shift 2
arr=("$@")
printf '<%s>\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: thanks, how can I delete "empty" elements from array?

Comment: Ask a new question to ask a new question.